# Me voy a ver pájaros, ¿tiene un nombre esa actividad?

Tags: vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

He contratado con una empresa una actividad para hacer una serie de caminos por los que nos iremos encontrando con pájaros y tendremos un guía que nos irá diciendo de qué va el tema.

*Duda*: ¿Tiene algún nombre específico esta actividad?

*Por ejemplo: probar vinos (mientras un experto te habla de ellos) = **Enoturismo***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La primera palabra que me viene a la cabeza es [*pajarear*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RTLBC5u), pero en plan broma. Eso sí, el DRAE recoge este término y la primera de sus acepciones podría ser útiles (aunque yo siempre que la escucho pienso en la segunda):

> 1. intr. Cazar pájaros.
>   2. intr. Andar vagando, sin trabajar o sin ocuparse en cosa útil.

Mirando un poco más veo que se ha acuñado el concepto ***turismo ornitológico*** o también *orniturismo*. Buscando es común encontrar el primer término, mientras que el segundo parece bastante menos generalizado.

Del artículo de la Wikipedia [turismo ornitológico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turismo_ornitol%C3%B3gico):

> El turismo ornitológico, también llamado orniturismo, turismo de observación de aves o aviturismo, es la actividad que implica desplazarse desde un sitio de origen hacia un destino específico con el interés de observar la avifauna local en su entorno natural.

Por tanto, si quieres una palabra técnica, usa orniturismo. Si quieres que se entienda mejor, usa turismo ornitológico.

En ambos casos se usa el prefijo *ornito-*

> [**ornito-**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=REiYAnC)
>   *Del gr. ὀρνιθο- ornitho-, y este de ὄρνις, -ιθος órnis, -ithos.*
>   1. elem. compos. Significa 'ave', 'pájaro'. Ornitológico, ornitomancia.

Comment: Me quedo con turismo ornitológico pues. Gracias por la rápida respuesta :)

Comment: @Alex ¡que lo disfrutes! Y si allí te hablan de otro concepto, no dudes en volver al sitio para contárnoslo :)

Answer (score 6):

La actividad de ir a ver pájaros se denomina *observación de aves* o *avistamiento de aves* y consiste básicamente en observar aves y estudiarlas, a veces sacar fotografías o registrar sus sonidos y cantos.

Buscando por internet páginas que traten el tema parece que también se utiliza bastante el término en inglés *birdwatching* aunque generalmente en el nombre de los clubs o asociaciones o junto con la denominación en español:

> La observación de aves o birdwatching es una afición(...)

El turismo relacionado con esta actividad como ha explicado **@fedorqui** en su respuesta se denomina generalmente *turismo ornitológico*.

Comment: ¡Muy buena respuesta!

Comment: @fedorqui la respuesta buena es la tuya que es lo que preguntaba el OP, la mía puede servir para complementarla un poco

Answer (score 0):

La palabra es

> orniturismo

El prefijo ya ha sido explicado en otras respuestas.